# from a point of view of performance, is the same extended methods than linq to entities?

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

When I work with entity framewrk, if I am not wrong with the terminoly, I can use linq to entities and extended methods.

I name linq to entities to this query:

```
var myResult = (from c in myCOntext.Customers
                where c.ID >= 35
                select c).List();
```

And I name extended methods to this way:

```
List<Customers> lstResult = myContext.Customers.Where(c=>c.ID >= 35).ToList();
```

In both cases I get the same result, but I wonder if one way is more efficient than other, because in both case EF must convert the query to T-SQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly the same. The *declarative query syntax* (your first code snippet) gets translated at *compile time* into methods that call the *standard query operators/extension methods* (your second code sippet) (Brief reference is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397947.aspx)).

In the end the compiled code is the same and this code (LINQ to Entities), when it runs, performs the translation into SQL. Choosing snippet one or two is just a matter of personal taste and preference. However, sometimes you can only use extension method syntax because not all supported methods have counterparts in query syntax.